# Drop down list to filter data using query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I am stuck with a sheet that I want to filter the data using drop down list. here is a sheet attached with two drop down list in the "DETAILS" tab were the data having same name with different category and result. So if I select a name from drop down 1, I want to display the full rows with same name. and when I select a car from the drop down 2 it must display only the name and that car and its details only. when i searched for a solution in Youtube I found out a similar one but I tried it in all way. I couldn't bring that in my sheet. Please help me

Sheet link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VsLKHSZsTMeBctnINnsixKISgNkTHDV-dkO4ORsDjgI/edit#gid=595280251

video link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLW8SerwnJo

Answer (score 1):

I added it to the sheet, but the code you're looking for is:

```
=query(LIST!A1:G12,"Select * where B contains '"&$A2&"' and C contains '"&$B2&"'")
```

### REFERENCES

[Query Language API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

[QUERY Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Edited to add: I notice that it isn't pulling all of the dates over on my end; I think this might have to do with the differences in date format.

Comment: pls take a look into that sheet if that i inserted any row under A1, its also comes in the "DETAILS" tab A5. pls take a look.. so that u can understand